# how to insert symbol(,) to result in SQLAlchemy level?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
#mapping class 
class Billing(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'billing'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  billingdate= Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
  amt = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
  rate = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
  fk_cpid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.cpid'))

#run
  query = self.mssql_session.query(Billing.billingdate).all()
```

result

> $83749283 => $83,749,283

how to insert symbol(,) at Billing.billingdate in ONLY SQLAlchemy level?

Replace, SubString?

Answer (score 1):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Billing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'billing'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    billingdate= Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    _amt = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    rate = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    fk_cpid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.cpid'))

    @hybrid_property
    def amt(self):
        return '${:,}'.format(self._amt)
```

Hopes, this code can help you.